# how to import JSON data into VS2012 to plot highcharts

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-2012, highcharts

I want to import the data from JSON file into my VS2012 c# code so that I can plot my highcharts based on the data in JSON file.
I have checked many video on youtube and file docs but couldnt locate single code that runs and give an output as required.

Do give me a sample code that will map a data from JSON file, use it in vs2012 and plot the highcharts.

----------------**Updated Question-------------**

Below is the function I am trying to call in java-script where I want to evoke data from JSON format, but I am not able to call my function, below is my code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'spline'
            },
            series: [{}]
        };

        alert("outside");
        $.getJSON('data.json', function (data) {
            alert("INside");
            options.series[0].data = data;
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });

    });
</script>
```

and want to pass the data to the highcharts ,Since I am novice, any help will be greatly appreciated.

==============EDIT 2 =====================================
the Json file am trying to use for the data is in following format.

```
[
[1,12],
[2,5],
[3,18],
[4,13],
[5,7],
[6,4],
[7,9],
[8,10],
[9,15],
[10,22]
]
```

Thank You.

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Any errors showing up? What is the format of data.json?

Comment: @wergeld there is no error and I think the function is not executing

have edited the Question for reference along with the Json file m using

Comment: In javascript console you have no error? Interesting - are your alerts showing up?  "Outside" and "INside"?

Comment: @PawełFus.. yes, I am showing alerts outside and inside,but of no use can you please suggest me a simple eg to render json data on Highcharts..

Comment: nah.
MY outer alert is working but its not executing inner alert.
please suggest a simple code that reads data from JSON file.

Comment: It seems that getJSON is not called, or json doens't exist. Please ensure that you don't receive 404 error in yoru console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If JSON file is not rendering on the browser and your are getting 404 error then you might be facing the mime type handling problem, please refer the below link which resolves the issue,

[getJSON method does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976153/getjson-method-does-not-work/19985149?noredirect=1#comment29752617_19985149)

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC Server Code:

```
namespace ABPMVCTest.Web.Controllers
{
[AbpMvcAuthorize]
public class HomeController : ABPMVCTestControllerBase
{
    static Random _ran=new Random();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ContentResult GetJsonResult()
    {

        var dataList = new List<ChartDataFormat>();
        GetData(dataList, "总收入");
        GetData(dataList, "投币收入");
        GetData(dataList, "扫码充电收入");
        GetData(dataList, "售线收入");
        var dataJsonStr=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataList,new JsonSerializerSettings(){ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()});
        return Content(dataJsonStr);
    }

    private static List<ChartDataFormat> GetData(List<ChartDataFormat> dataList, string key)
    {

        var list = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {

            list.Add(_ran.Next(1, 3000));
        }
        dataList.Add(new ChartDataFormat
        {
            Name = key,
            Data = list
        });

        return dataList;
    }
}

class ChartDataFormat
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<int> Data { get; set; }
}
}
```

Client javascript Code:

```
$(function() {

Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {

            printChart: '打印图表',
            downloadJPEG: '下载为JPEG图片',
            downloadPDF: '下载为PDF',
            downloadPNG: '下载为PNG图片',
            downloadSVG: '下载为SVG矢量图',
            months: ["一月", "二月", "三月", "四月", "五月", "六月", "七月", "八月", "九月", "十月", "十一月", "十二月"],
            weekdays: ["周日", "周一", "周二", "周三", "周四", "周五", "周六"],
            shortMonths: ["1月", "2月", "3月", "4月", "5月", "6月", "7月", "8月", "9月", "10月", "11月", "12月"],
    }
});
var nowDate = new Date();
var option = {

    chart: {
        type: 'area'
    },
    title: {
        text: '收入趋势图'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: '没有选择时间范围的话，默认显示当日/月前后3天/月的数据'
    },
    credits: {
        enabled:false
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        title: {
            enabled: false
        },
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            day: "%Y-%m-%d",
            week: "%A",
            month: "%Y-%m",
            year: "%Y"
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: '单位：元'
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return this.value;
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        valueSuffix: ' 元',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            day: "%Y-%m-%d,%A",
            week: "%A开始, %Y-%m-%d",
            month: "%Y-%m",
            year: "%Y"
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        area: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            lineColor: '#666666',
            lineWidth: 1,
            marker: {
                lineWidth: 1,
                lineColor: '#666666'
            }
        },
        series: {
            pointStart:Date.UTC(nowDate.getFullYear(),nowDate.getMonth(),nowDate.getDate()-3) ,
            pointInterval: 24 * 36e5 //一天
        }
    },
    series: [{}]
}

var url = "/Home/GetJsonResult";

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    option.series = data;
    $('#container').highcharts(option);
});

 });
```

Comment: This is my achievement method.May you succeed!